# How to fix this "possible null pointer dereference" critical issue in Sonar?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

The following is the method in question.

```
public String getCarById(Integer carId) {
  ResponseEntity<CarString> response = rTempl.getForEntity(url, CarString.class,
        of("car-id", carId.toString()));
  log.debug("code: {}", response.getStatusCode());
  return Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getCarString();
}
```

The full error is as follows.

```
Possible null pointer dereference in <package>.CarRegistryClient.getCarById(Integer) due to return value of called method
```

Is using `Objects.requireNonNull()` not enough for Sonar?

UPDATE: Added missing but relevant code to the method. No code is missing now.

Comment: `response` might be null. Though the error message is confusing.

Comment: That sonar error shows up if sonar believes that the NPE is inevitable (i.e. there is a code path that guarantees it). The code you pasted does not have such a path; clearly there's something in the code you elided. For example, perhaps the code you elided indicates that `response` is either definitely null, or you are nullchecking `response`, which makes sonar identify 'response' as potentially null. Separately, your Objects.requireNonNull here is completely useless; remove it. (rNN throws NPE; dereferencing it, which you do here, also does. There is no point to your rNN invoke).

Comment: @rzwitserloot: I added the missing but obviously relevant code back to the code snippet in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough that was the fix and Sonar was happy.

```
public String getCarById(Integer carId) {
  ResponseEntity<CarString> response = rTempl.getForEntity(url, CarString.class,
        of("car-id", carId.toString()));

  CarString responseBody = response.getBody();
  assert responseBody != null

  log.debug("code: {}", response.getStatusCode());
  return response.getBody().getCarString();
}
```

I still don't get how this is different from my previous solution via `Objects.requireNonNull()`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `rTempl.getForEntity`'s method is explicitly declared as potentially returning `null`, and your code then just dereferences what `getForEntity` gave you without checking anything. Your `requireNonNull` code checks that `response.getBody()` returns non-null; it does not check if `response` itself is non-null.

And code is still missing. Whatever might rTempl be?